# Google Cloud storage library to read from Cloudstorage and download to local/on-prem?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I see options to authenticate and read Buckets/Objects from Google cloud.
How do i copy the objects directly to my local/on-prem where the below program might run? I see some methods like downloadTo, copyTo for blob but looks like it is to copy/download inside google cloud itself, if i am not wrong. The downloadTo path doesn't allow me to configure a server with the path.

(Note - I am aware of the gsutil command, but I want it programmatically to download files, if possible)

```
StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID).setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();
Storage storage = options.getService();
Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`downloadTo`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html#downloadTo-java.nio.file.Path-) does download to where you are executing the code.

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
//other imports and setup before this

String bucketName = "MY-BUCKET";
String filename = "MY-FILE.EXTENSION";
Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName, filename);
if (blob != null) {
    blob.downloadTo(Paths.get('path/where/you/want/to/save/the/file.extension'));
}
```

This code will take the file that's in the bucket, and download it to whatever path you want, wherever you are running it.

Comment: Thanks. that worked. I was initially incorrectly setting the Path, and that was resolving to Cloud storage path when used downloadTo.

Comment: Is there an easier way to download all the files from Cloud storage bucket directory into some local location directory? I tried like below to list files and download.  


Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(BUCKET_NAME, BlobListOption.prefix("ingestion/output/"));
     Iterable<Blob> blobIterator = blobs.iterateAll();
      boolean headerFlag = false;
      for(Blob b:blobIterator) {
       System.out.println(b.getName());
       if(headerFlag) {
        b.downloadTo(Paths.get("C:\\WORK\\gcpdownload\\"+ b.getName()));
       }       
       headerFlag = true;       
    }